# HTML how to save input depending on selected dropdown value

Tags: html, select, input, drop-down-menu

**HTML:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="" method="post">
      <label>Select Fridge or Freezer</label>
      <select name="FridgeFreezer">
        <option value="Fridge 1">Fridge 1</option>
        <option value="Fridge 2">Fridge 2</option>
        <option value="Fridge 3">Fridge 3</option>

      </select>

      <label>Temperature °C</label>
      <input type="number">
      <label>Comments</label>
      <textarea name="comments"></textarea>
      <button type="button" name="button">Save</button>

    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Goal:**

How can I select a value from the dropdown menu, for example, I have selected `Fridge 1` from the menu, I then type some value in the `Temperature °C` and `Comments` box. Next select another value from drop down box as an example `Fridge 2` and start a fresh input, but if I go back to `Fridge 1` the data previously inputted to be visible.

What do I need to look into in terms of research? I am not sure where to look or what keywords to search.

Comment: I think you need JavaScript!

Comment: Do you want to do this with javascript or jQuery ?

Comment: When you say "save", are you thinking of saving it just for that session? Or saving it to that browser for future sessions? Or saving it to the server? etc etc

Comment: @AlwaysHelping JavaScript preferably

Comment: @DBS On click I will loop through all values for `fridge 1,2 and 3` see if they are empty, and if they are then do not do anything. If all are filled out, then send to MySQL database using `Node JS`

Comment: In that case, I would listen for the `change` event for the `select` element, and at that point, store the values for the other fields in an array of objects that represent each option (something like `{id: 'Fridge 1', temp: '2', comments: 'example'}`) and then search the array for any values you should load for the new id.

Comment: @DBS that's a very useful comment - I appreciate that. You got any useful links/resources to read?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've put together a quick example of what I mentioned in the comments, using a simple array of objects the maintain each options previous state.

When the select is changed, we:

- Check to see if we have an object for the previous id
- If we do, update that object, otherwise, create a new one with the new values
- Update the current id (We store this externally as it's lost by the time the `change` is executed)
- Check for any saved data for the newly loaded id and load that if it exists

```js
var savedValues = []
var currentId = document.getElementById("fridgeFreezer").value

function handleChange() {
  // The new values for the fridge with id currentId:
  var temp = document.getElementById("temperature").value
  var comments = document.getElementById("comments").value
  
  // Save these values for the previous id
  // - First, check to see if we already have a record we can update
  var save = savedValues.find(save => {
    return save.id === currentId
  })
  // - If we do, update it, otherwise create a new record
  if (save) {
    save.temp = temp
    save.comments = comments
  } else {
    savedValues.push({
      id: currentId,
      temp: temp,
      comments: comments,
    })
  }
  
  // Update the current id to the newly selected option
  currentId = document.getElementById("fridgeFreezer").value
  
  // Load any previously saved data for this new id
  save = savedValues.find(save => {
    return save.id === currentId
  })
  // If we find a previous value, load it, otherwise empty the inputs
  if (save) {
    document.getElementById("temperature").value = save.temp
    document.getElementById("comments").value = save.comments
  } else {
    document.getElementById("temperature").value = ''
    document.getElementById("comments").value = ''
  }
  
}

// Attach the event listener to the document
document.getElementById("fridgeFreezer").addEventListener('change', handleChange, false)
```

```css
label {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="post">
  <label>Select Fridge or Freezer</label>
  <select name="FridgeFreezer" id="fridgeFreezer">
    <option value="Fridge 1">Fridge 1</option>
    <option value="Fridge 2">Fridge 2</option>
    <option value="Fridge 3">Fridge 3</option>
  </select>

  <label>Temperature °C</label>
  <input type="number" id="temperature">
  <label>Comments</label>
  <textarea name="comments" id="comments"></textarea>
  <button type="button" name="button">Save</button>

</form>
```

Comment: Are you able to explain/expand what is happening at `save = savedValues.find...` not sure what is happening

Comment: @LV98 The `find` method takes a function that's used to filter each element in an array and returns the first item where the function returns true. I've used an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions): `save => { return save.id === currentId }` which means that each element in the array is passed into the function (that's what `save` is in this context), one at a time, and it keeps going until either one of the elements in the array has an `id` property that matches `currentId` and returns true, or it reaches the end.

Comment: Documentation for [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) (The link wouldn't fit into the first comment's character limit)

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend using Vue.js for this. State management is very easy in it. The way I would do this is:

```js
    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: function(){
            return {
            devices: [{id: 0, name: 'fridge1', tempCelcius: 39, price: 20}, 
            {id: 1, name: 'fridge1', tempCelcius: 39, price: 30}, 
            {id: 2, name: 'fridge1', tempCelcius: 39, price: 40}],
            selected = ''
            }
            }
            
        
        })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <select v-model="selected">
            <option disabled value="">Please select one</option>
            <option v-for="device in devices" v-bind:key="device.id">{{ device.name }}</option>
        </select>
        <span>{{ selected }}</span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is a start, it doesn't quite work yet but [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html) is where you'll find how to implement